# webpack configuration webpack-dev-server does not compile files on the fly

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-dev-server

I have following webpack configuration file.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'scripts.min.js'
},

resolve: {
    root: [
        path.resolve('./src'),
        path.resolve('./node_modules')
    ]
},

entry: './src/app.js',

module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel'
        }
    ]
},

devServer: {
    // compress: true,
    inline: true,
    stats: 'errors-only'
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ 'mangle': false, sourcemap: false })
]
```

};

The problem is that when I run `webpack-dev-server` command, it does run the server but when I make changes to any js file they are not compiled on the fly. So I had to stop the server and run `webpack` and then run `webpack-dev-server` command to make things work.

**How can I make `webpack-dev-server` work so that when watches for all js, css, scss files and compile those fly?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with an IDE, you have to disable "safe write".

> Note that many editors support “safe write” feature and have it enabled by default, which makes dev server unable to watch files correctly. “Safe write” means changes are not written directly to original file but to temporary one instead, which is renamed and replaces original file when save operation is completed successfully. This behaviour causes file watcher to lose the track because the original file is removed. In order to prevent this issue, you have to disable “safe write” feature in your editor.

http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#hot-mode